# Adobe analytics integration with adobe target

Tags: optimization, adobe-analytics

I have a question around how a typical adobe analytics and adobe target integration works and how the data connect between the two systems.  Basically I don’t believe my integration is working as intended based on the follow things I experience in adobe analytics.

A customer can be part of a adobe target test without ever visiting the page of the test. Requiring additional filtering in adobe analytics to remove this visit which never make it to the a/b test page.

After a test is ended adobe analytics continues to track visits to the test after it has been ended or paused. Requiring additional filtering to make sure we only look at the correct time frames in our adobe analytics data.

I have never experienced this with any other a/b testing tool I have worked with over 5 a/b testing tools now so I really doubt this is the intended experience adobe has created in it product but I wanted to check with others.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Analytics and Adobe Target are two separate tools, implemented separately, so no pausing or turning off the Target campaign does not stop Adobe Analytics from tracking the page, in general.  If you setup a page specifically for a Target campaign and no longer want Adobe Analytics to track the page when the campaign is over, then you need to remove or disable Adobe Analytics from the page.

Having said that.. I'm not sure I understand why you would want to do that. Maybe I misunderstand you, but it sounds like you are trying to effectively have date ranges by virtue of not having active campaigns or tracking on a given page. Why aren't you using date range filters?

Answer (score 0):

Situation 1: *"A customer can be part of a adobe target test without ever visiting the page of the test."*
This shouldn't be happening in Target if you intend the test to only apply to visitors of a certain page, though there are reasons you could see it in Analytics. I'd look first to see if this has to do with how the test was set up. If it was set up properly and you're only seeing this in Analytics, not Target, then it could be a number of things. I won't get into detail here, but it could be there was a counting error due to cookies blocked or deleted, the segment being built in Analytics after the test started, etc.

Situation 2: *"After a test is ended adobe analytics continues to track visits to the test after it has been ended or paused."*
This will happen until you delete the segment in Analytics that you made from your test. I've seen some segments remain for years just because no one bothered to delete them.

These are great tools, but you need to follow some guidelines in using them together. We've used Analytics with Target for data, but you need to make sure you're not trying to correlate that data between the two. They count very differently. Even for the same segment and metric, you'll see widely different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the raw data, the columns post_tnt and post_tnt_action solve for this. [See this article for a better explanation than I can give.](https://www.softcrylic.com/blogs/adobe-analytics-for-target-a4t-a-look-under-the-hood/)

Even having the test information in the list_var style (the one with persistence that gets used in Workspace) and the on-the-hit style, an event of "2", impression, is not a guarantee that content was returned by Target. Another test could over ride it, or something could fail in the browser.